# Codeiginter 4 Batch Insert

Tags: sqlite, codeigniter-4

I am using CI4 to create an app that reads a playlist of series containing more than 100K records.

The problem is that it takes alot of time and also exhausts memory even after adding:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', -1);
```

Ok i can increase memory_limit but it still takes a hell lot of time.

I insert into the db using:

```
$this->db->transStart();
$seriesTable = $this->db->table('tbl_series');
$seriesTable->emptyTable();
$seriesTable->insertBatch($series);
$this->db->transComplete();
```

And the `$series` array element (episode) is as follows:

```
$epidose = array(
  'clm_series_name' => $station['author'],
  'clm_series_media_url' => $station['media_url'],
  'clm_series_group' => $station['group'],
  'clm_series_square' => $station['thumb_square'],
  'clm_series_type' => $station['type'],
  'clm_series_season' => $station['season'],
  'clm_series_episode' => $station['episode']
);
```

I would like to have suggestions on how to decrease the execution time.
Using transactions didn't help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should provide more details on "_Using transactions didn't help_". I don't know Code Igniter, but the _normal_ way to successfully increase insert-speed in SQLite is to do batched inserts (several hundred to several thousand within one transaction). It's very possible that CI4, and/or whatever wrapper you're using between PHP and SQLite, is doing it's _own_ handling of transactions, to _how_ you tried "_using transactions_" might not have worked how you hoped. Show this and someone who know CI4 might be able to help.

Comment: I inserted transaction begin and end encapsulating the batch insert. Maybe i did it really generic and i basically did nothing special but thats how i tried it (updated code). Can you please elaborate a little more on the batched inserts? Do you mean chunk the array and insert it chunk by chunk?